# Estimation parameters using Generalized Method of Moments and Generalized Empirical Likelihood with R

Tags: r, logistic, estimation, generalized-moments

I have two density functions: $h_{1}(x)$, $h_{2}(x)$.

I want to estimate parameters from one dataset using $ h_{1} $ and $ h_{2} $ andthe GMM estimator or the GEL : from the article "Computing Generalized Method of Moments and Generalized Empirical Likelihood with R"

I want to estimate the parameters : $ \delta $, $\beta $ $ \mu $ and $ \sigma $.

$h_{1}(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sigma \left( \frac{1}{6}-\frac{\delta}{2}+ \frac{\delta^{2}}{2} + \beta\right) }\left[ \frac{\left[ \Phi^{2}\left( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right] }{2}-\delta \Phi\left( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)+\left( \frac{\delta^{2}}{2} + \beta\right) \right] \phi\left( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$

Where $ \Phi $ and  $ \phi $ are the cumulative and the density function of standard normal distribution.

$h_{2}(x)=\dfrac{1}{P(1)} \left[ \dfrac{\left( e^{\frac{x-\mu}{s}}\right)^{2} \left( \frac{1}{2}-\delta+\frac{\delta^{2}}{2}+\beta\right) - \beta e^{\frac{x-\mu}{s}}+\left(\frac{\delta^{2}}{2} + \beta\right)}{s\left( 1+e^{\frac{x-\mu}{s}}\right)^{4}} \right].$

So my problem is how to do it with R, I am beginner in R but it is the only software that can deal with this method of estimation.

I want to use GMM and GEL as in [this article.](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmm/vignettes/gmm_with_R.pdf)

Comment: I'm not from an econometrics background, but this GMM approach is suspiciously close to the *GEE* approach. Are you aware of whether they're the same?

Comment: GEE2 are actually a type of GMM estimator.